# ionic - How to implement notification including show screen and ringing on background mode like a incoming call

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

How to implement notification like a voice call in LINE, Messenger, WhatsApp or any voice call app?   when anyone calls to you, it will show screen accept or reject even though the app runs on background mode. Currently, I implement notification using FCM https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase/  it works but I want notification like incoming call then user accepts it will open some link with capacitor InAppBrowser. (the notification should have a sound for ringing about a minute and show screen) because of normal notification, it won't work when the user leaves the phone.